# Headphone jack issue on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, laptop, audio, speakers, headphones

Just this morning I was using my computer normally. Then I started having a problem on my laptop, and I am not getting any audio on my headphones or external speakers. Yet, they are detected: when I plug them in I get that message saying "You just plugged in a device into the audio jack". Also, I have sound on the laptop's inbuilt speakers..

I have tried:
1.Installing different audio drivers from Realtek;
2.Rebooting;
3.Playing around with the Realtek's software definintions.

In the software I see no mention to the headphones, though they are detected by the taskbar icon when I plug them in.

This problem is on Windows 8 64 bit. I don't know if it is related, but this morning I also did some updates on Linux (this is a dual boot laptop). Yet, it is important to note that everything works perfectly on Linux.

Do you know how I can get it back to work? Thanks in advance

Specs:
Asus G73Jw
Windows 8 64bit

Comment: how do you know if your audio jack isnt causing problems?

Comment: Well, I cannot be very certain, but it would be very strange as the computer is only 1 year old, and it was working fine this morning. No buzzes, no nothing..
Also, while I was testing different stuff (installing, unninstalling drivers, etc.) at some point it started working again. But when I switched from the external speakers to the headphones, it stopped again and didnt get back on.
Yes, still, I am assuming it is not a hardware problem

Comment: Further: when I boot into Linux it works perfectly!

Comment: Ok that makes sense, it must be driver related then.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what changed, but something made it work. I had tried installing/replacing drivers, changing setup on Realtek's software to no avail. But for some reason, it is now working. Thanks anyway